# Express.js application bug: form filed values do not persist

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, mean-stack

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

There is an "Add New Post" form of course, with an `addPost()` method in the controller;

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const post = new Post();

    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
    post.full_text = req.body.body;

    console.log(post);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('danger', errors.array());
        req.session.save(() => res.render('admin/addpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
            page_heading: 'Dashboard',
            page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
            post: post
        }));
    } else {
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The form view:

```
<form action="./post/add" method="POST" class="mb-0">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= req.body.title %>" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="<%= req.body.excerpt %>" placeholder="Excerpt" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Full text">
            <%= req.body.title%>
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Post" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
    </div>

</form>
```

Suppose some of the *required* form fields are filed-in, but *not all* of them.

The form view is rendered again, with error messages for the *empty required fields*. But the required fields that are not empty should persist  their data. But they do not.

Using this syntax does not work either `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= post.title %>" placeholder="Title" />` even though the line `console.log(post)` shows this in the console, **as expected**:

```
{
  updated_at: 2020-03-18T10:49:17.199Z,
  created_at: 2020-03-18T10:49:17.199Z,
  _id: 5e71fcbe7fafe637d8a2c831,
  title: 'My Great Post',
  short_description: '',
  full_text: ''
}
```

[image: The title filed should hold the value "Title"]

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

The generated HTML of the form:

```
<form action="./post/add" method="POST" class="mb-0">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="" placeholder="Excerpt">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Full text"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Post" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check if ejs is working properly? Add this in your html and see <%= 2 + 2 %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you'll have to change on your controller and view, I have mentioned both changes below

On your controller

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    var form = {
        titleholder: req.body.title,
        excerptholder : req.body.excerpt,
        bodyholder: req.body.body
    };
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            req.flash('danger', errors.array())
            //req.session.save(() => res.redirect('../addpost'));
            res.render('admin/addpost',{
                layout: 'admin/layout',
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                page_heading: 'Dashboard',
                page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
                form:form});
    } else {
```

Code after else is same as you already have, I have added a `form` object and changed your `res.redirect` to `res.render`

And this will be the code for your view

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex px-2">
            <h6 class="m-0"><%= page_subheading %></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-2">
            <form action="./post/add" method="POST" class="mb-0">               
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.titleholder : '' %>" placeholder="Title" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="<%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.excerptholder : '' %>" placeholder="Excerpt" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Full text"><%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.bodyholder : '' %></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group mb-0">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Post" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
                </div>
        </form>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

values for `value` attribute is changed. I have also created a pull request for your github project.

Comment: Your answer is missing the part that is actually posting the post, but you have solved my specific problem. If interested, here is the **[complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809261/4512005)**. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i haven't changed anything on the `else` part I only changed the `if` part. There was a pull request on your git as well. Never mind.

Comment: There was a spell error, please fix inside `var form` in `addPost` method, this should be the correct spell `excerptholder` i wrote `expertholder`

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
                <form action="./post/add" method="POST" class="mb-0">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%=post && post.title? post.title : ''%>" placeholder="Title" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="<%=post && post.short_description? post.short_description : ''%>" placeholder="Excerpt" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Full text"><%=post && post.full_text? post.full_text : ''%></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Post" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: I will try it out as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 0):

The complete working code adding posts ca be seen below.

In the controller:

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {

    var form = {
        titleholder: req.body.title,
        excerptholder: req.body.excerpt,
        bodyholder: req.body.body
    };

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const post = new Post();
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
    post.full_text = req.body.body;

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('danger', errors.array())
        res.render('admin/addpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
            page_heading: 'Dashboard',
            page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
            form: form
        });
    } else {
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
<form action="/dashboard/post/add" method="POST" class="mb-0">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.titleholder : '' %>" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="excerpt" value="<%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.excerptholder : '' %>" placeholder="Excerpt" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Full text">
            <%= typeof form!='undefined' ? form.bodyholder : '' %>
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Post" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
    </div>
</form>
```